# Javascript - Detect if user is coming from a Google Adwords ad

Tags: javascript, google, google-ads

Is it possible to detect if my visitors are coming to my website via a Google Adwords Ad?

It would like to change the telephone number for those users only, that way I can measure the success of my adwords campaign with the number of calls.

Comment: You can do that on the server side by looking at `HTTP_REFERER`, or better yet, make the link in the Adwords ad have a parameter that you catch on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the special utm_ query string parameters mentioned here:
http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156114

Then switch your phone number out based on (for example) utm_campaign

If you use the auto tagging feature (on by default) the parameter to look for is gclid:
http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55596

Comment: After clicking on an AdWords ad and arriving at a `?glcid=...` link, I presume after the user clicks on another link, that `gclid` parameter disappears. Is there a way to know if the traffic originated from AdWords even after navigating to a second page?

Answer (score 0):

On the server you need to grab the value of "HTTP_REFERER"

Also, Google Analytics should be able to do this for you, out of the box.